# cron job won't write to file

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks

I run a windows 2003 server and tried to run a code like this every 15 minutes:

```
require("db_connect.php");
$conn = db_connect();

//list online brukere - flytt funksjon til separat side for bedre ytelse
$time = time() - 900;
$query ="SELECT username FROM tbl_user WHERE last_online >= $time";
$online_users; 
if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $online_users .= $row["username"].":";
    }
    $result->close();
}   

$filename = "online_users.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fputs($fp,$online_users);
fclose($fp);
```

When I go to the url or run it from the command line it works and write to file. But the task just run and don't save the file.. What's wrong?

Comment: Redirect the output to log file. Check if the query is actually returning any results. Check if you have permission to create a file at the specified location.

Comment: what cron command do you use?

Comment: If your script works when you call it by URL, then it's probably not a permission problem. Sounds like a cron not being called at all (should be able to verify this in your http log files). Please tell the cron solution you are using and how you configured it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$filename = dirname(__FILE__) . "/online_users.txt";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$filename = "online_users.txt"; <-- this is using relative path
```

You might not have permission to write to relative path.

So, chose another path with enough write permission, and **please, use absolute path instead**.